# How to Multiple setOnAction on the same button JavaFX

Tags: java, validation, user-interface, button, javafx

I'm trying to make the button **jugar** validates and returns value from a textbox and 3 drop boxes, there must be a way to validate more than one values, for example, the login button, when you type username and password.

here is the code

```
        package application;

        import javafx.scene.control.Button;
        import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
        import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
        import javafx.application.Application;
        import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
        import javafx.event.EventHandler;
        import javafx.geometry.Insets;
        import javafx.stage.Stage;
        import javafx.scene.Scene;
        import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
        import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
        import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;


        public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

        // crea los botones 
        Button historial;   
        Button jugar;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
//nombre de la ventana principal
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Football Simulator 2016");
```

here the drop lists

```
    //crea los drop list
    ChoiceBox<String> jugadasArbitro = new ChoiceBox<>();
    jugadasArbitro.getItems().addAll("Saque de banda","Tiro de esquina","Falta","Falta(Tarjeta amarilla)", "Falta (Tarjeta roja)", "Mano","Posicion adelantada","Penal","Fuera de juego", "Gol");
    ChoiceBox<String> jugadasOfensivas = new ChoiceBox<>();
    jugadasOfensivas.getItems().addAll("Pase","Pase largo","Tiro a puerta");
    ChoiceBox<String> jugadasDefensivas = new ChoiceBox<>();
    jugadasDefensivas.getItems().addAll("Intercepcion");
```

here i have setOnAction listeners

```
    //inicializa botones
    TextField tiempo = new TextField();
    historial = new Button("Historial");
    historial.setOnAction(this);
    jugar= new Button("Jugar");
    jugar.setOnAction(e -> isInt(tiempo,tiempo.getText()));
    jugar.setOnAction(e -> getArbitro(jugadasArbitro));
    jugar.setOnAction(e -> getOfensiva(jugadasOfensivas));
    jugar.setOnAction(e -> getDefensa(jugadasDefensivas));

    //forma del Gui y posiciona los botones
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    grid.setVgap(8);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    GridPane.setConstraints(historial, 1, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(jugar, 2, 2);
    GridPane.setConstraints(jugadasArbitro, 3, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(jugadasOfensivas, 3, 4);
    GridPane.setConstraints(jugadasDefensivas, 3, 5);
    grid.getChildren().addAll(historial, jugadasArbitro,jugadasDefensivas,jugadasOfensivas,jugar,tiempo);

    //tamanio de la ventana
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 540,300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

the methods to read the drop box value

```
//leen el valor de los drop box
private void getDefensa(ChoiceBox<String> jugadasDefensivas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String opcionDefensa = jugadasDefensivas.getValue();
    System.out.println(opcionDefensa);
}

private void getOfensiva(ChoiceBox<String> jugadasOfensivas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String opcionOfensiva = jugadasOfensivas.getValue();
    System.out.println(opcionOfensiva);
}

private void getArbitro(ChoiceBox<String> jugadasArbitro) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String opcionArbitro = jugadasArbitro.getValue();
    System.out.println(opcionArbitro);
}

//valida que el tiempo solo sea INT
private boolean isInt(TextField tiempo, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        int minutos = Integer.parseInt(tiempo.getText());
        return true;
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
    System.out.println("Error: introduzca numeros solamente");
    return false;

}

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just have it all in one `OnActionHandler`? Or if you want it to only process one of them have a variable determine which to test (would be changed through other events and interactions).

```
jugar.setOnAction(e ->{
    isInt(tiempo,tiempo.getText());
    getArbitro(jugadasArbitro);
    getOfensiva(jugadasOfensivas);
    getDefensa(jugadasDefensivas);
});
```

OR

```
jugar.setOnAction(e -> {
    if(method == 1)
    {
        isInt(tiempo,tiempo.getText());
    }
    else if(method == 2)
    {
        getArbitro(jugadasArbitro);
    }
    else if(method == 3)
    {
        getOfensiva(jugadasOfensivas);
    }
    else if(method == 4)
    {
        getDefensa(jugadasDefensivas);
    }
});
```

Just depends on how you need it.

Answer (score 0):

well this is easy, just have to set.OnAction(e ->{(whatever) });
example:

```
jugar.setOnAction(e ->{ isInt(tiempo,tiempo.getText());
    getArbitro(jugadasArbitro);
    getOfensiva(jugadasOfensivas);
    getDefensa(jugadasDefensivas);
    });
```